# update multidimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

**I have** a multidimensional array and I have echoed the keys and values in a foreach loop. I would like to have an update box next to the 'id' (key) to update the id value and also next to the 'size' (key) to update the size value

**Problem**::
Bellow is my code, the input boxes echo out the right values for each key, but when I hit the update button, it doenst update...

The update doesnt have to be in a foreach loop, btw. I just thought it will be easier

Thanks in advance for all the help

**CODE**

```
        <?php
session_start();

 $array=array(
'Homer' => Array
(
    'id' => 111,
    'size' => 54

),
  'Marge' => Array
(
    'id' => 222,
    'size' => 12

),
'Bart' => Array
(
    'id' => 333,
    'size' => 3
)
);
// update if submit
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    // i tired a number of things here but it was all errors 

}
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['simpsons']))
$_SESSION['simpsons']=$array;


// getting each array in a foreach loop         
foreach( $_SESSION['simpsons'] as $character => $info) { 

        echo $character.': id is '.$info['id'].', size is '.$info['size'];
        //add and update input box for each ' id '      and    '  size '


?>

<!-- input for id -->
<input name="<?php $character ?>" value="<?php echo $info['id'] ?>">
<!-- input for size-->
<input name="<?php $character ?>" value="<?php echo $info['size'] ?>">

<?php

echo"<br/>"; 
}

?>

<!-- submit button for the form -->
<input class="inputbox" type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You just forgot to write `echo` in your input `name` attribute. and need to set `name` attribute as array. So you input tag look like `<input name="<?php echo $character ?>[]" value="<?php echo $info['id'] ?>">`.

Comment: @hardiksolanki Even if he did he'd have two input elements with the same name which aren't a radio, so technically one is getting overwritten. He has to use `[]` brackets

Comment: @FlorianMüller check my updated answer.

Comment: @hardiksolanki Therefore I added the sentence about the brackets in the exact same moment ;D

Comment: @FlorianMüller: I have updated my answer before your comment :D

Answer (score -1):

You have two inputs which have the same name (twice `<input name="Homer" ...>`). I'd suggest a generic solution:

```
<input type="text" name="names[]" value="<?php echo $character;?>" />
<input type="text" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $info['id'];?>" />
<input type="text" name="sizes[]" value="<?php echo $info['size'];?> />
```

Then you'll recieve in your PHP-Code the data via post (if you don't want to see the name as an input field, make it `type="hidden"`).

```
<?php
$names = $_POST['names'];
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
$sizes = $_POST['sizes'];
foreach ($names as $key=>$value) {
    //name is $value
    //id is $ids[$key]
    //size is $sizes[$key]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, It still doesnt allow me to update it. do I put $_SESSION['simpsons'][$character] = $ids; and $_SESSION['simpsons'][$character] = $size; in the foreach statement?

Comment: You are updating nothing in your question. If you want to update the session values, you may execute in my loop: `$_SESSION['simpsons'][] = array('name'=$value,'id'=>$ids[$key],'size'=>$sizes[$key]);`

Answer (score -1):

foreach should be

```
    foreach( $_SESSION['simpsons'] as $tt2) {
       print_r($tt2);
        foreach($tt2 as $character => $info){

       echo $character.': id is '.$info['id'].', size is '.$info['size'];
       //add and update input box for each ' id '      and    '  size '
      }
   }
```

Comment: Nothing prints using it that way :S

Comment: inside first foreach print_r($tt2);

Comment: Thanks :). but what about updating the size and id. i still can get it to work ;s

Comment: print_r($tt2) prints anything? what is prints?